# openlayer: how to add icons or patterns onto LineString

Tags: geometry, icons, styles, openlayers-3

I am very new to using OpenLayers and new to mapping. I want to create a LineString Feature Object, which appears in some complex patterns,but I only find the color-attribute to set it. Is there some way to solve this problem? Adding an icon representing it like Point object or setting some pattern are needed. However, we can't fine the method for this.Could you have some way,please help me.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306976/add-image-along-the-linestring/306979

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional property for your line Stroke style:

```
lineDash: [41,17]
```

Check this answer:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/148570